# Возвращать определенный интерфейс доступа к объекту

Tags: c#, ооп, архитектура

Задача следующая: Есть следующий класс:

```
public class Processor
{
    public void Operation1()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Некоторые внешние пользователи данного класса при использовании любого из методов будут выполнять операцию в рамках очереди задач, другие же пользователи - в рамках своего потока, в своем контексте (соответствующая логика внутри Operation). Вопрос заключается в том, как этим разным классам-потребителям иметь соответствующую версию Processor. На ум приходит только что-то вроде:

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    void Operation1();
    void Operation2();
}

public class ExternalProcessor : IProcessor
{
    public void Operation1()
    {
        //QUEUE
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        //QUEUE
    }
}

public class InternalProcessor : IProcessor
{
    public void Operation1()
    {
       //...
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public static class Router
{
    public static IProcessor GetContract(bool external)
    {
        if(external)
            return new ExternalProcessor();
        else
            return new InternalProcessor();
    }
}
```

Недостатки такого подхода - надо держать по 2 экземпляра объекта Processor (это не DTO объект, а объемный диспетчер, пересоздавать каждый раз нельзя, есть состояние)
Другим подходом был бы пронос флага в каждый из методов и, соответственно, запуск в рамках очереди или в вызываемом потоке в зависимости от него. Решение тоже не самое красивое.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли более изящные способы решения данной задачи?

Comment: А почему б вместо интерфейса не создать абстрактный клас. Унаследовать от него 2 класса и переопределить в них ваш метод operation.

Comment: В этом случае все-равно придется держать 2 процессора, разве нет?

Comment: *Недостатки такого подхода - надо держать по 2 экземпляра объекта Processor* — не понял что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: InternalProcessor  и ExternalProcessor. Мне нужно создать их заранее от отдавать в зависимости от запроса